# iOS Detecting Index of UIButton Press Dynamic

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, tags, uibutton

So basically I am making an API call to retrieve a list of Charities. I then place all this in an array and set UIButtons dynamically.

I then allow the user to select the charity and display a view with that index's data.

My loop is here;

```
for (int i = 0; i < [self.imageArray count]; i++) {

    NSDictionary *listRoles = [self.imageArray objectAtIndex:i];

    NSString *charityName = [listRoles objectForKey:@"name"];
    NSString *charityDescription = [listRoles objectForKey:@"description"];
    NSString *charityImage = [listRoles objectForKey:@"image"];

    UIImage *pImage=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:charityImage]]];;

    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setImage:pImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTag:i];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:button];
```

I then have a clicked method;

```
- (void)buttonClicked:(UIButton*)button
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
    CharityProfileViewController *cpvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CharityProfile"];
    [self presentViewController:cpvc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

How can I retrieve the index, I know that I could set random tags for the UIButton but how would I still know which one?

Comment: using tag u can get the index

Comment: you have set the tag property of UIButton. You can easily find button.tag..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the tag value of button as

```
[button setTag:i+1];
```

then in Button Action

```
- (void)buttonClicked:(UIButton*)button
{
     NSLog(@"Button Tag : %d",button.tag);

    NSLog(@"Selected Index Object : %@",[self.imageArray objectAtIndex:button.tag-1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either retrieve the a tag for your button by `button.tag` or add your buttons to an array and use then `[buttonsArray indexOfObject:button]` in your `buttonClicked:` method